# partial sum involving factorials

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

Here is an interesting series I ran across.

It is a binomial-type identity.

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(2n-k)!\cdot 2^{k}}{(n-k)!}=4^{n}\cdot n!$

I tried all sorts of playing around, but could not get it to work out.

This works out the same as $\displaystyle 2^{n}\prod_{k=1}^{n}2k=2^{n}\cdot 2^{n}\cdot n!=4^{n}\cdot n!$

I tried equating these somehow, but I could not get it. I even wrote out the series.

There were cancellations, but it did not look like the product of the even numbers.

$\displaystyle \frac{(2n)!}{n!}+\frac{(2n-1)!\cdot 2}{(n-1)!}+\frac{(2n-2)!2^{2}}{(n-2)!}+\cdot\cdot\cdot +n!\cdot 2^{n}=4^{n}\cdot n!$.

How can the closed form be derived from this?.  I bet I am just being thick. I see the last term is nearly the result except for being multiplied by $2^{n}$.  I see if the factorials are written out, $2n(2n-1)(2n-2)(2n-3)\dots$ for example,  then 2's factor out of $2n, \;\ 2n-2$ (even terms) in the numerator.

There is even a general form I ran through Maple. It actually gave a closed from for it as well, but I would have no idea how to derive it.

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(2n-k)!\cdot 2^{k}\cdot (k+m)!}{(n-k)!\cdot k!}$.

In the above case, m=0.  But, apparently there is a closed form for $m\in \mathbb{N}$ as well.

Maple gave the solution in terms of Gamma:  $\displaystyle \frac{\Gamma(1+m)4^{n}\Gamma(n+1+\frac{m}{2})}{\Gamma(1+\frac{m}{2})}$

Would anyone have an idea how to proceed with this?.  Perhaps writing it in terms of Gamma and using some identities?. Thanks very much.

Comment: Your "general form" doesn't make sense if $m$ is a positive integer, because you'll get factorials of negative integers: $(k-m)!$.  Perhaps you mean $(m-k)!$ instead?

Comment: If you flip the summation order of your first sum, it becomes $$2^n n!\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n+k}{k}\frac1{2^k}$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(2n-k)!}{(n-k)!}2^k\tag{1}
&=n!\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2n-k}{n-k}\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}\\\tag{2}
&=n!\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^{n-k}\binom{n+k}{k}\binom{n-k}{j}\\\tag{3}
&=n!\sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{k=0}^{n-j}\binom{n+k}{n}\binom{n-k}{j}\\\tag{4}
&=n!\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{2n+1}{n+j+1}\\\tag{5}
&=n!\;2^{2n}
\end{align}
$$

1. rewrite $2^k$
2. $k\mapsto n-k$
3. change order of summation and $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$
4. $\sum_k\binom{n-k}{i}\binom{m+k}{j}=\binom{n+m+1}{i+j+1}$
5. Split $\sum_j\binom{2n+1}{j}=2^{2n+1}$ in half

Comment: A virtuoso use of binomial coefficient identities!

Answer (score 5):

Here's a combinatorial proof for J.M.'s reformulation (after dividing out $n!$):

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n+k}{k} 2^{n-k}= 4^n.$$

Suppose you flip coins until you obtain either $n+1$ heads or $n+1$ tails.  After either heads or tails "wins" you keep flipping until you have a total of $2n+1$ coin flips.  The two sides count the number of ways for heads to win.

*For the left side*: Condition on the number of tails $k$ obtained before head $n+1$.  There are $\binom{n+k}{k}$ ways to choose the positions at which these $k$ tails occurred from the $n+k$ total options, and then $2^{n-k}$ possibilities for the remaining flips after head $n+1$.  Summing up yields the left side.

*For the right side*: Heads wins on half of the total number of sequences; i.e., $\frac{1}{2}(2^{2n+1}) = 4^n$.

Comment: Nice! More direct than my detour through *Concrete Mathematics*.

Answer (score 2):

Dividing out $2^n\cdot n!$ and changing variables, your equation follows from (5.20) on page 167 of *Concrete Mathematics* by Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik. If you don't have this reference, I can add more details later.

$$\sum_{k\leq m}{m+k\choose k}2^{-k}=2^m\qquad\text{integer}\quad m\geq 0.\qquad\qquad (5.20)$$

---

Just for fun, here is a probabilistic proof of (5.20).
Suppose we toss a fair coin until we see either $m+1$ heads
or $m+1$ tails. Let $J$ be the number of trials *prior* to the final 
toss, and consider $\mathbb{P}(J=j)$ for $m\leq j\leq 2m$. 
We get $J=j$ by either $m$ heads in the first $j$ tosses followed
by a head, or $m$ tails in the first $j$ tosses followed by a tail.
By symmetry, we find
$$\mathbb{P}(J=j)=2{j\choose m}\left({1\over 2}\right)^j\left({1\over 2}\right)
={j\choose m}\left({1\over 2}\right)^j.$$

Since the total probability adds to one, we get 
$$\sum_{m\leq j\leq 2m} {j\choose m}\left({1\over 2}\right)^j=1.$$
Putting $k=j-m$ in this sum and multiplying by $2^m$ gives (5.20).

Comment: Interesting reference (GKP) thanks! Page 247 they propose to prove that $\sum_{k\gt m}{m+k\choose k}2^{-k}=2^m$ using the additional fact that  $(1-x)^{-1-n} = \sum^{\infty}_{k=0} \binom{k+n}{n} x^k$ (see (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/84523/an-asymptotic-question))

Comment: @Raymond Thanks for the link!

Comment: I am so sorry. I had a typo in the original post. I even looked it over to make sure and still missed it. That should have been $(k+m)!$.  I made some edits. Of course, that changed the closed form which can be written with factorials instead of Gamma:  $\displaystyle \frac{m!4^{n}(n+\frac{m}{2})!}{(\frac{m}{2})!}$.  Again, my apologies and thanks for all the responses.  No, I do not have Concrete Mathematics, but I think I can obtain it. I will look into it. Thanks

Comment: @Cody: you definitely should; it's a nice book to have!

Answer (score 1):

This identity can be re-written as
$$\sum_{k=0}^n {2n-k \choose n-k} 2^k = 4^n.$$

Start from
$${2n-k \choose n-k} =
\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^{2n-k}}{z^{n-k+1}} \; dz.$$

This yields for the sum
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(1+z)^{2n-k}}{z^{n-k+1}} 2^k \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{(1+z)^{2n}}{z^{n+1}}
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(2z)^{k}}{(1+z)^k} \; dz.$$

We can extend the sum to infinity because when $n-k+1 \le 0$ or $k \ge n+1$ the integrand of the defining integral of the binomial coefficient is an entire function and the integral is zero. This yields

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{(1+z)^{2n}}{z^{n+1}}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(2z)^{k}}{(1+z)^k} \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{(1+z)^{2n}}{z^{n+1}} \frac{1}{1-2z/(1+z)} \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{(1+z)^{2n+1}}{z^{n+1}} \frac{1}{1-z} \; dz.$$

Thus the value of the integral is given by
$$[z^n] \frac{1}{1-z} (1+z)^{2n+1}
= \sum_{q=0}^n {2n+1\choose q} = \frac{1}{2} 2^{2n+1} = 4^n.$$

A trace as to when this method appeared on MSE and by whom starts at this
[MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/792567/evaluating-combination-sums).