# Evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{j=0}^{n}{{j+n-1} \choose j}\frac{1}{2^{j+n}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, binomial-coefficients

> Evaluate $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{j=0}^{n}{{j+n-1} \choose j}\frac{1}{2^{j+n}}$$

I don't understand where to start.  Please help.

Comment: I think the limit will be $\frac{1}{2}$.

See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48411/evaluate-lim-n-to-infty-sum-j-0njn-1-choose-j-frac12jn

Comment: Seems related to the negative binomial distribution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As guy notes, the sum has a probabilistic interpretation.
Suppose that you  toss a fair coin until you have either $n$ heads 
or $n$ tails. The probability that you need $j+n$ tosses in total is 
$2{j+n-1\choose j}(1/2)^{j+n}$ for $0\leq j\leq n-1$. 
The factor of $2$ in the front comes from the two cases, whether the series ends with a head or a tail.

Since the probabilities
add up to one, we have
$$2\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} {j+n-1\choose j}\left({1\over2}\right)^{j+n}=1,$$
and so
$$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} {j+n-1\choose j}\left({1\over2}\right)^{j+n}={1\over2}.$$

The sum considered by the OP has one additional term that goes to zero. 
So as $n\to\infty$, 
$$\sum_{j=0}^{n}{{j+n-1} \choose j}\frac{1}{2^{j+n}}={1\over2}+{2n-1\choose n-1}{1\over 2^{2n}}\to{1\over2}.$$

---

**Added:** The additional term has the product representation
$${2n-1\choose n-1}{1\over 2^{2n}}={1\over2}\prod_{j=1}^n \left(1-{1\over 2j}\right).$$
Using the elementary arguments [from my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58560/elementary-central-binomial-coefficient-estimates/58562#58562) we get the upper bound
$${2n-1\choose n-1}{1\over 2^{2n}}\leq{3\over 8\sqrt{n+1}},$$
which shows that the extra term goes to zero. Of course, there are other ways to do this.

---

See [this question as well](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95236/partial-sum-involving-factorials/95242#95242).

Comment: +1.  Maybe an explanation of why the additional term goes to zero, too?

Comment: Added reference: See equation (5.20) in *Concrete Mathematics* by Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland +1, There is a sign typo though: $$ \sum_{j=0}^n \binom{n+j-1}{j} \frac{1}{2^{n+j}} = \frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{2^{2n}} \binom{2n-1}{n-1} $$

Comment: @Sasha Thanks for that.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Please see a [related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289101) of mine.